# Java string array sorting according to 3 criterias

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

I have a string array in Java. I need to sort it by the number of character "a"s within the word (decreasing order). If some words contain same number of character a, then I need to sort those words by their lengths(decreasing order). And if the length is same, then alphabetically.

Example array:

["aaaasd","a","aab","aaaabcd","ef","cssssssd","fdz" ,"kf","zc","lklklklklklk","l"]

needs to be sorted like:

["aaaabcd","aaaasd","aab","a","lklklklklklk","cssss ssd","fdz","ef","kf","zc","l"]

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: yes I was thinking to loop through the array to get the numbers of "a"s on the words. but I am newbie in Java and I don't know if this is a good way to do it. Plus even if it is a good way to start, I have no idea what to do on the next step for the 2. and 3. criteria. So stuck in here.

Comment: shmosel yes. Version 8 Update 40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's already mentioned, just use `Arrays.sort()` method with your own `Comparator`:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (countA(o1) == countA(o2)) {
            if (o1.length() == o2.length()) {
                // Compare lexicographically
                return o2.compareTo(o1);
            }
            // Compare by the length
            return o2.length() - o1.length();
        }
        // Compare by the number of 'a'
        return countA(o2) - countA(o1);
    }

    private int countA(String s) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int pos = 0; pos < s.length(); ++pos) {
            if (s.charAt(pos) == 'a') {
                total++;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
});
```

Where `arr` is your `String` array.

The main idea is to check criterias according to their precedence and check new criteria only if objects are equal according to all previous criterias.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I would never get the idea of comparator in reverse order with ifs by myself. I am a Java newbie and had no idea about this usage at all.

Comment: @CeyhunGanioglu No problem ;) All such comparators are written in the same manner and depend on programming language only in details.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
// compare count of 'a' chars, descending
Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.comparing(s -> s.chars().filter(c -> c == 'a').count(), Comparator.reverseOrder());

// then string length, descending
comparator = comparator.thenComparing(String::length, Comparator.reverseOrder());

// then natural (alphabetical) order
comparator = comparator.thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());

// apply sort
Arrays.sort(strArr, comparator);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a util method in `Arrays` class:

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Just write your own implementation of `Comparator` and pass it as parameter along with the array of strings you wish to sort by it.

Comment: I've already had a look at the comparator examples on the internet but gave me no idea about solving this kind of problem with 3 criterias.